# Enter Key binding in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

So, I've been trying to bind the enter key to press the button I have in this python program -- yes I've seen the numerous other questions related to this, but none of their code worked with this program for whatever reason. Posting code below to see if anyone has a good solution.

The below code does everything as expected -- it will pull up the GUI, show the goofy jar-jar picture, the button, and the entry fields with the prefilled text, but the enter key on my keyboard will not produce a result as it happens when I press the button with the mouse.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageTransform
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = tk.Tk()


class guiMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        myFrame = tk.Frame(master)

        # logo

        logo = Image.open('jar.jpg')
        logo2 = logo.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo2)
        self.logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo2)
        self.logo_label.image = logo2
        self.logo_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

        # instructions
        self.instructions = tk.Label(master,
                                     text="Input your email address and password to extract email attachments.\n "
                                          "You should also select the folder you wish the attachments to reach.")
        self.instructions.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3)

        # store the user login info in variables
        def storeUserLogin():
            clientEmailInput = self.emailEntry.get()
            clientPasswordInput = self.passwordEntry.get()
            print(clientEmailInput, clientPasswordInput)

        # delete email prefill on click
        def onEmailClick(event):
            self.emailEntry.configure()
            self.emailEntry.delete(0, 100)  # this deletes the preexisting text for email entry
            self.emailEntry.unbind('<Button-1>', self.on_click_id)

        # delete pw prefill on click
        def onPWClick(event):
            self.passwordEntry.configure()
            self.passwordEntry.delete(0, 100)  # this deletes the preexisting text for email entry
            self.passwordEntry.unbind('<Button-1>', self.on_click_id2)

        # email entry box
        self.emailEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=50)
        # emailEntry = tk.StringVar(None)
        # emailEntry.set("Email Address")
        self.emailEntry = tk.Entry()
        self.emailEntry.insert(0, "Email Address")
        self.emailEntry.configure()
        self.emailEntry.grid(column=1, row=1)

        # on-click function
        self.on_click_id = self.emailEntry.bind('<Button-1>', onEmailClick)

        # enter key function
        def enterFunction(event=None):
            master.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None, loginButton.invoke())

        # password entry box

        self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry()
        self.passwordEntry.insert(0, "Password")
        self.passwordEntry.grid(column=1, row=2)

        # on click function
        self.on_click_id2 = self.passwordEntry.bind('<Button-1>', onPWClick)

        # button to login
        def loginButton():
            self.loginButtonText = tk.StringVar()
            self.loginButton = tk.Button(master, textvariable=self.loginButtonText, font="Arial",
                                         commands=lambda: [storeUserLogin(), enterFunction()],
                                         width=5, height=2,
                                         bg="white", fg="black")
            self.loginButtonText.set("LOGIN")
            self.loginButton.grid(column=1, row=4)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=250)
        self.canvas.grid(columnspan=3)


g = guiMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The binding code is inside `enterFunction()` which is never called in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're Binding the **loginButton** function in another function which is never called and you are writing the OOPs wrong here. You shouldn't define your functions in **init** function.Here is some changes that i made in your code. I am not good at explaining but i hope this will help. I wrote reasons too in code where i change the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageTransform
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = tk.Tk()


class guiMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #definr master in Class so we can use it from entire class
        self.master = master
        myFrame = tk.Frame(master)

        # logo

        logo = Image.open('Spitball\Spc.jpg')
        logo2 = logo.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo2)
        self.logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo2)
        self.logo_label.image = logo2
        self.logo_label.grid(column=1, row=0)
        
        #Create Email Entry box (we are creating Email and Password entry box when class is initialize)
        self.emailEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=50)
        self.emailEntry.insert(0, "Email Address")
        # emailEntry = tk.StringVar(None)
        # emailEntry.set("Email Address")
        # self.emailEntry = tk.Entry() # You should not create two entry boxes with same name
        # self.emailEntry.configure() # We dont need to configure email entry here 

        #Create Password Entry box (we are creating Email and Password entry box when class is initialize)

        self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry()
        self.passwordEntry.insert(0, "Password")
        
        #Grid the email and password entry box.Here email entry box will display first beacuse we grid it first.
        self.emailEntry.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.passwordEntry.grid(column=1, row=2)

        # instructions
        self.instructions = tk.Label(master,
                                     text="Input your email address and password to extract email attachments.\n "
                                          "You should also select the folder you wish the attachments to reach.")
        self.instructions.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3)

        #Create Login Button 
        self.loginButtonText = tk.StringVar()
        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self.master, textvariable=self.loginButtonText, font="Arial",
                                    command=self.storeUserLogin,
                                    width=5, height=2,
                                    bg="white", fg="black")

        # I dont see here the use of Canvas so i commented out it. 
        # self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=600, height=250)

        # on-click function
        self.on_click_id = self.emailEntry.bind('', self.onEmailClick)


        # on click function
        self.on_click_id2 = self.passwordEntry.bind('', self.onPWClick)

        #Bind enter key with loginButtonFunc
        self.master.bind('',self.loginButtonFunc)


    def storeUserLogin(self):
        # store the user login info in variables
        clientEmailInput = self.emailEntry.get()
        clientPasswordInput = self.passwordEntry.get()
        print(clientEmailInput, clientPasswordInput)

        # delete email prefill on click
    def onEmailClick(self,event):
        self.emailEntry.configure()
        self.emailEntry.delete(0, 100)  # this deletes the preexisting text for email entry
        self.emailEntry.unbind('', self.on_click_id)

        # delete pw prefill on click
    def onPWClick(self,event):
        self.passwordEntry.configure()
        self.passwordEntry.delete(0, 100)  # this deletes the preexisting text for email entry
        self.passwordEntry.unbind('', self.on_click_id2)

        # button to login
    def loginButtonFunc(self,event=None):
 
        self.loginButtonText.set("LOGIN")
        self.loginButton.grid(column=1, row=4,pady=5)

        # self.canvas.grid(columnspan=3)


g = guiMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Much appreciated -- I will test this code and implement some changes when I get home this evening. The was probably a lot of junk code in there from testing things which is why I left that other canvas in, along with some other things. Anyways, thank you so much!